# Does deleting a person in Chrome delete it in all computers?

Tags: google-chrome

So I'm currently at work we're we regurarily change computers and I unknowingly synced all my personal chrome stuff into a pc here.

After quite a bit of work I managed to seemingly remove all of if but then I found out there's this "person 1" which can be just click to access all my stuff

And now I'm now at this step of removing which I'm not sure if it's exactly what I want:

[image: http://prntscr.com/onv8xq]

I do want to delete this person 1 but does this remove it everywhere or just in this computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Chrome profile is specific to the Windows user account that you are signed in to on that PC.

Not only does deleting your Chrome profile not remove it from other computers, it also does not remove it from Chrome on other Windows user accounts on the *same* computer.

All this does is remove your Chrome profile from Chrome in the Windows user account you are currently signed in to, right now. If you theretically ever logged on under another Windows user account on that PC and created another profile in Chrome there, you would have to log in to that Windows account again to remove the Chrome profile.

Comment: Great!

Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Answer (score -1):

You may delete the profile, but it seems that the data may stay on disk and can
be restored
(see [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/30ityv/i_just_deleted_a_person_1_profile_from_chrome_and/)).

I would suggest uninstalling Chrome, scrubbing out all folders containing
"Chrome" and re-installing, just to be safe.

Comment: The OP is asking if a deleted Chrome profile automatically propagates the deletion to *other* computers. The answer to the question is unequivocally no! :)

Comment: @wrecclesham: I'm adding the additional info that it might not fully propagate even to the local computer.